# Why is the delta so tiny?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am currently trying to create a scrolling camera and have successfully done so, however I found that the value of delta is very small and was wondering why this was the case.

```
Shooter: 0.016785555
Shooter: 0.016596204
Shooter: 0.016559256
Shooter: 0.017374134
Shooter: 0.015813652
Shooter: 0.016723463
Shooter: 0.016657267
Shooter: 0.0167522
```

Should I bump them up? Or am I missing something entirely?

Comment: Perhaps this question is clear to those with better specific subject knowledge, but I'd be surprised if you can get much assistance without supplying some example code that generated those values.

Comment: Or at least a description of what you are doing...my best guess would be that the frame rate is really high so the movement each frame is tiny.

Comment: And what is your intention to this question? If it works as expected, why are you asking if you should bump up the values? It's like asking why the acceleration of your car is that slight. That's just how it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This delta, aka as deltaTime, is the time your last frame took to render.

Let's assume that your app has 60 frames per second (FPS), then your deltaTime should roughly be 0.01666... which is your case as well.

Usually you will use it like this:

```
float speed = 10f;
float positionX = positionX + (speed * deltaTime);
```

If this is part of your render routine, which runs in every frame, your positionX will increase by 10 every second. Without deltaTime your speed will totally depend on the speed of your device.